# DB2Audit Facility not works fine

Tags: db2

I am using db2audit facility to monitor database and instance activities. I configured data path but the live logs for the databases are not available in that location.

And also I have not configured audit policy for a database but it is generating live logs and the db2audit archive also works for that database.  I don't know what is the use case of assigning and auditing a database using audit policies.

So my questions are,
1.  Why live logs are not generating in datapath.(db2audit archive also not working since there is no active log file in data path)
2.  db2audit archive works and active log file is generated even without configuring db2audit policy.  What is the reason. Will db2audit start will start auditing for all databases irrespective of audit policies?

> **db2audit describe:**

DB2 AUDIT SETTINGS:

Audit active: "TRUE "

Log audit events: "BOTH"

Log checking events: "BOTH"

Log object maintenance events: "BOTH"

Log security maintenance events: "BOTH"

Log system administrator events: "BOTH"

Log validate events: "BOTH"

Log context events: "BOTH"

Return SQLCA on audit error: "FALSE "

Audit Data Path: "/home/test/db2logs/active/"

Audit Archive Path: "/home/test/db2logs/"

> **ls -l** on data path.

-rw------- 1 test test   9000 Dec 30 10:19 db2audit.db.SELVASK1.log.0

-rw------- 1 test test   8394 Dec 30 10:18 db2audit.db.SELVASK.log.0

these 2 databases(SELVASK, SELVASK1) don't have audit policies.

> Output for **SELECT COUNT(1) FROM SYSCAT.AUDITUSE WHERE OBJECTTYPE=''**  for both databases

1

---

0

1 record(s) selected.

> I found this in db2diag.log.  It happens while trying to archive the database and it fails to create archive file as intended.

```
2019-12-26-15.27.25.376000+330 I317589969F856       LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 13144                TID : 8160           PROC : db2syscs.exe
INSTANCE: DB2                  NODE : 000           DB   :         
APPHDL  : 0-104                APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.191226095725
AUTHID  : SYSTEM               HOSTNAME: DESKTOP-R9O62O0
EDUID   : 8160                 EDUNAME: db2agent (instance) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, bsu security, sqlexDb2auditArchiveRename, probe:350
RETCODE : ZRC=0x860F000A=-2045837302=SQLO_FNEX "File not found."
          DIA8411C A file "" could not be found.
DATA #1 : Hexdump, 47 bytes
0x00000027407FACF2 : 433A 5C73 656C 7661 5C65 6C61 7465 7374    C:\selva\elatest
0x00000027407FAD02 : 5C64 6174 615C 6462 3261 7564 6974 2E64    \data\db2audit.d
0x00000027407FAD12 : 622E 5445 5354 3132 332E 6C6F 672E 30      b.TEST_DB.log.0

2019-12-27-20.52.20.159033+330 I1729969E910          LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 15851                TID : 140506994566912 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: test                 NODE : 000            DB   :         
APPHDL  : 0-3707               APPID: *LOCAL.test.191227152221
AUTHID  : TEST                 HOSTNAME: ubuntu18
EDUID   : 2851                 EDUNAME: db2agent (instance) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, bsu security, sqlexDb2auditArchiveRename, probe:350
RETCODE : ZRC=0x860F000A=-2045837302=SQLO_FNEX "File not found."
          DIA8411C A file "" could not be found.
DATA #1 : Hexdump, 51 bytes
0x00007FCA557F8DF0 : 2F68 6F6D 652F 7465 7374 2F64 6232 6C6F    /home/test/db2lo
0x00007FCA557F8E00 : 6773 2F61 6374 6976 652F 6462 3261 7564    gs/active/db2aud
0x00007FCA557F8E10 : 6974 2E64 622E 454C 4154 4553 542E 6C6F    it.db.TEST_DB.lo
0x00007FCA557F8E20 : 672E 30                                    g.0
```

Comment: Please, update your post with the `db2audit describe` command output, listing of both directories specified in the `Audit [Data | Archive] Path` lines, the result of  the `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM SYSCAT.AUDITUSE WHERE OBJECTTYPE=''` query in your database.

Comment: Hi, @MarkBarinstein I updated the question. please check it

Comment: Even SYSCAT.AUDITPOLICIES has no entries in it.

Comment: I don’t see the result of the `ls -l ...` command on both directories. And what’s the database name?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein updated the question.  And now the active logs are generated for other databases. But don't know why the files were deleted suddenly.

Comment: The situation with active instance audit and absence of the  `/home/test/db2logs/active/db2audit.instance.log.0` (active instance audit) file, and no database audit policies and growing `/home/test/db2logs/active/db2audit.db.DBNAME.log.0` (active database DBNAME audit) file is really strange, if you don't mess something. You should check the db2diag.log file and open a Case with IBM support, if there is no something related to the audit activity in db2diag.log.

Comment: Actually instance.log.0 is available.  There are lots of files in the dir so I forgot to mention it in question.  I will open a case with IBM for this issue.  But what about the automatic file removal issue? I found something from db2diag.log and I updated it in question. please check it.

Comment: Your db2diag.log is from Windows, whereas other info from Unix / Linux. Why do you mix the information from different systems? Db2 **does not** remove active audit logs itself.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein sorry for the confusion.  I have 3 servers. 2 Windows and 1 Linux server.  All the 3 servers have this issue.  and at the time of archive failure event, that is the only log available in diagnostic log file in all 3 servers.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I updated the log from Linux server also. pls check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205060/discussion-between-selva-and-mark-barinstein).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of good articles:
**[Db2] Simple test case shell script for db2audit instance and database level auditing**
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1075779

I would like to recommend you to review it and try to follow steps as describes first of all.  Once you find it works, try to modify what you want to audit with referencing manual pages at the bottom of that article.

Here is key part of the page for database level auditing:

```
db2audit configure reset
db2audit configure scope all status both errortype normal
db2audit configure datapath $HOME/temp/db2audit
db2audit configure archivepath $HOME/temp/db2audit
db2audit describe

### start and stop database level auditing ###
db2 -v "create audit policy DB_Policy1 categories all status both error type normal"
db2 -v "audit database using policy DB_Policy1"
db2audit start

db2 -v "create table t1 (c1 int, c2 int)"
db2 -v "insert into $USER.t1 values (1,1)"
db2 -v "select * from $USER.t1"
db2 -v "delete from $USER.t1"
db2 -v "audit database remove policy"
db2audit stop
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, @hidehy thanks for the response.  I actually started auditing a long back and it was worked good. But suddenly the active log files were removed automatically and the db2audit archive fails to archive the active logs.  What might be the reason for these sudden changes?

Comment: Hi @Selva Generally speaking, it should not be changed suddenly automatically.  There might be changed by someone or something.  I would try to re-create policy to see if the problem persists or not.  Or try to review db2diag.log for any error right before the behavior has changed.